# How to not get blocked by LinkedIn CORS policy when sending a POST request through their API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am creating a simple app in which I would like to  post a Article Share to LinkedIn using their API. I have researched a lot and have got things working in Postman, but I am not getting it to work on my hosted website. Here is the code I am using:

==============================================

```
    async LinkedIn(sm_webData) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sm_webData.accesstoken}`,
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            author: `urn:li:person:${sm_webData.urn}`,
            lifecycleState: 'PUBLISHED',
            specificContent: {
              'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent': {
                shareCommentary: {
                  text: this.postTitle,
                },
```

==============================================

Here is the response I get in the console:

==============================================

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts' from origin     'https://myURL.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

==============================================

I have tried a few variations including using my URL in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header along with setting the request's mode to 'no-cors', although I believe the latter will simply cause more problems. I have included my website domain/url in the "Widgets" of the "Domains" of the "Additional Settings" in the LinkedIn Developers page as well as have set them in the OAuth 2.0 Settings authorized redirect URLS. I am a bit stuck, because I am getting this to work using Postman and have researched a few other forums, but responses are a bit dated as well. I fairly understand most CORS concepts as I have programmed some of my own APIs using PHP in the backend. Nonetheless, I am simply stuck at this moment and would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

I tried this solution:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cross-origin-resource-sharingcors-issues-few-fixes-ritika-sharma/
Also I read most of the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin

Comment: I did a few more tests with the Twitter API and I am coming to the conclusion that most of these APIs do not allow calls to be made from hosted websites or frontends such as what I am working on. I did a few more tests in the backend and it seems to work that way, particularly curl and PHP. will try this solution.